# Netbeans there is a way to create an empty project?

Tags: java, netbeans

I 'am a Visual Studio (VB.net / C#) programmer and I have installed Netbeans.

When I open a new project 'Java application' don't create a new EMPTY project but add the project to the other previous projects.

In Visual Studio (and all other IDEs) if I choose 'new project'  after I see ONLY my new project and not all projects.

How can I do to create only a new empty project with Netbeans ?

P.S.

I don't want use Eclipse becouse I need a Visual Ide (form in particual) and Netbeans see better for this point.

Thank you !

Comment: You can simply close those projects you don't need (anymore). You might want to look into Project Groups as well.

Comment: I ended up closing all windows in the navigator, and then dragging and dropping my folder into netbeans

Answer (score 1):

- In Tools-Plugins install Freeform project Extras.
- Create

  - Java Free-form project or
  - empty Ant-based project or
  - Skeletal Ant-based project

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the other projects and choose "Close Project"

Comment: Each time I need to do this for all projects ?? for my opinion this is only a loss of time. For Example with Eclipse is not necessary do this.

Comment: I would suggest combining this suggestion with the project grouping feature mentioned above, so you could close a entire group at once.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

File->Project Group->New Group...

Answer (score 0):

There's no explicit form for doing that.
As a workaround you can create a project of any type according what you will want to do (Java, C++, PHP, HTML, etc), and then delete the resources created automatically except "nbproject" folder.
With this approach you have something similar to an empty project.
I recently used this trick for group some modules created for PrestaShop and then push them to Git VCS as if it were a single project, when actually each module is an independent project folder.

[image]